# Lucene: collect all values from a field in a sorted collector

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to collect all values for a specific docvalues field in documents from a query in a collector extending SimpleCollector.

```
private Long values(int doc)
    throws IOException {
  SortedNumericDocValues values = context.reader().getSortedNumericDocValues(field);
  if (!values.advanceExact(doc) || values.docValueCount() == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return values.nextValue();
}
```

My problem is that i need to sort values by a specific sorted field. So i need to implement sorting in my collector. I've tried to extract code from TopFieldCollector but many classes are in package scope or private.

I'm using lucene 8.8 but i can advande to 9+ if needed.

Thanks.

I'm expecting to retrieve a list of values from a docvalues field using a collector, sorted by a sorted field.